# Brake flush vs. Replacing the brake fluid

Tags: brakes, brake-fluid, flush

Is a brake flush the exact same thing as replacing the brake fluid?

Or is there a difference?

Comment: The difference is that auto mechanics charge more for performing the one which you are not familiar with :)

Answer (score 13):

### There is no difference between the two.

To replace it, you have to flush out the old brake fluid with new fluid.

See [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22341/675) on how to bleed brake lines for more details.

Answer (score -1):

In some places, a brake flush might include some sort of additive used to clean the braking system. Its usually a gimmick.

Replacing the brake fluid itself is what it means. But flushes can vary between places and most of the time (from experience 99.999999999999%) its a gimmick to get your money.

Comment: It's not a gimmick when it's a recommended PM service from the manufacturer. Not saying it's never oversold, but it is a required maintenance service on several vehicles