# Changed wheel cylinders and now pedal only hits floor

Tags: brakes, sienna

I tried to bleed system but when I step on pedal no fluid comes out of the bleeder bolt.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Please explain *exactly* how you are bleeding the brakes.

Comment: It will take several steps on the pedal to bleed all the air out of a new wheel cylinder, keep the brake fluid reservoir full while doing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After brake bleed, pedal goes to floor](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/22320/after-brake-bleed-pedal-goes-to-floor)

Comment: When you mean wheel cylinders do you mean brake calipers? Or did you replace the master cylinder? Please give a lot more detail on the car and the exact steps and equipment you have used.

Comment: @GdD Wheel cylinders are part of a drum brake setup.

Comment: Aha, an old car then @NickC, I forgot about that.

Comment: Toyota Sienna 1997-2018 is an *old* car? Pedal-to-the-floor could also occur if there's a failure in the master cylinder. Is there a puddle on the garage floor?

Answer (score 1):

> *Most commonly the oil would have been dripped off the unit while removing and air would have mixed or there would be leak in the
>   system.*

If the case is too much air, you could solve it be slightly loosening the hose attached to the caliper or removing the bleeder screw completely that comes from the reservoir. 
Once you see the oil coming out from the screw, you could tighten it and carry on the brake bleeding task.

Here are few other troubleshooting steps:

***Reservoir :***
Check if the reservoir is full of oil. 
If you do remove the oil completly out of the system and you are refilling it again, please give some for the oil to fill the system

***Issues with Bleeder Screw:*** 
Please check if there is no Blockage in the Bleeder Screw.

***Hose:***
If the Bleeder screw is Good try removing the Hose that runs to the calipers. Check if the oil is comming out of it.

***Caliper Unit:***
Check if the brake fluid is leaking from any other point. 
If the rings are loose on the caliper piston or if the caliper piston is damaged there are chances of oil leakage from the piston

Answer (score 1):

On many brake systems you need to push the pedal down and close the bleeder valve before you let the brake pedal return,this is to avoid sucking air back into the system.

An other alternative is to use a brake bleeder with a return valve,this do only let brake fluid and air pass in one direction.

For the first solution you need to be two people one in the car pumping the brake and the other opening and closing the bleeder valve,you need to repeat this until all the air is gone so it only comes brake fluid when you push the pedal.

Be sure to keep an eye on the reservoir to avoid it running dry during this operation.